# How C Preprocessor expand the macro with ##?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

English is not my native language; thus I show the code to depict.

```
#define concat_temp(x, y) x##y
#define concat(x, y) concat_temp(x, y)
#define BAR 2

int main() {
    concat_temp(FOO, BAR)
    concat(FOO, BAR)
}
```

When I executed `clang -E`, the macros were expanded to

```
int main() {
    FOOBAR
    FOO2
}
```

Who can explain to me why `concat_temp` couldn't expand the `bar` to `2` but `concat` did the trick?

Comment: Nice! Never know about such things. But also good, that I did not know it because I avoid macros at all :-)

Comment: Funfact, `concat_temp(FOO, (BAR))` could still yield `FOO2` i think. Could be wrong, and compiler-dependant however.

Comment: @Shark <Compilation failed>lol

Comment: @unlsycn alright, point taken, i didn't mess with this macro stuff in like a decade. guess compilers evolved since then :D

Answer (score 5):

According to [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace),

> A `##` operator between any two successive identifiers in the *replacement-list* runs parameter replacement on the two **identifiers (which are not macro-expanded first)** and then concatenates the result.

The `##` operator operates on the *identifiers* themselves, so another pass of macro expansion is required if you want to "make string literal" or concatenate the values of `#define`-d macros.

Comment: Avoided my dupe hammer by 9 seconds ;D

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili In fact, by [4 more hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316139/350567) available.

Comment: Wow, [it did work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73193542/10147399). I am going to abuse this power...